# What is the BIP-44 Coin Type for Dash?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, bip

[BIP-44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) compliant HD wallet trees use the m/purpose'/coin_type'/ account'/change/address_index convention to derive private keys and associated addresses. For coin_type, BIP-44 makes a reference to [registered coin types](http://doc.satoshilabs.com/slips/slip-0044.html#registered-coin-types).  Will the Darkcoin index of 5 work for Dash?

**Compressed** DASH private WIF key (Darkcoin v0.6+ stores public keys in compressed format.):
`% echo 'very complex gibberish' | bx base16-encode | bx sha256 | bx hd-new | bx hd-private -d -i 44 | bx hd-private -d -i 5 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-to-ec | sed 's/$/01/' | bx base58check-encode -v 204`
XH2Yndjv6Ks3XEHGaSMDhUMTAMZTTWv5nEN958Y7VMyQXBCJVQmM

**Compressed** public address:
`% echo 'very complex gibberish' | bx base16-encode | bx sha256 | bx hd-new | bx hd-private -d -i 44 | bx hd-private -d -i 5 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-to-ec | bx ec-to-public    | bx ec-to-address -v 76`
Xb9HJy46M9u3SLAWVitS4eV6gEMuVFfZX2

**Uncompressed** DASH private WIF key:
`% echo 'very complex gibberish' | bx base16-encode | bx sha256 | bx hd-new | bx hd-private -d -i 44 | bx hd-private -d -i 5 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-to-ec | bx base58check-encode -v 204`
7rrHic4Nzr8iMSfaSFMSXvKgTb7Sw3FHwevGsnD2vYwU5btpXRT

**Uncompressed** public address:
`% echo 'very complex gibberish' | bx base16-encode | bx sha256 | bx hd-new | bx hd-private -d -i 44 | bx hd-private -d -i 5 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-to-ec | bx ec-to-public -u | bx ec-to-address -v 76`
XiEsuvDERQJT5S9RF7qcKGrm4omMsJ1PPg

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Dash should continue using the same HD index as Darkcoin. Only the coin name is changed.

So `5h` is the correct HD index for Dash.